# c# VSTO Loop through each row and set format based on another cell value

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have VSTO application that outputs rows into excel. I am trying to apply some formatting based on values in a cell. My requirement is if the column 'V' contains a value "No" in the cell, the entire row that has values in it needs to be of a background colour "light grey". Note: Column V is a drop down list of either yes or no in excel. So its not a normal text based cell. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
var last = uiWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

var lastUsedRow = last.Row < 6 ? 6 : last.Row;
var lastUsedColumn = last.Column;

var xlrange = uiWorksheet.get_Range("V:V");

if (xlrange.Value2.ToString() == "No")
{
    ???.EntireRow.Interior.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightGray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to look for a value in the column, you need to use `Find` and `FindNext` functions.
After it, you need to iterate over the results and change the color.

Please note following from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?view=vs-2019):

> The FindNext method's search wraps back to the beginning of the search
>   range after it has reached the end of the range. Your code must ensure
>   that the search does not wrap around in an infinite loop.

```
var xlrange = uiWorksheet.get_Range("V:V");

var searchFor = "No";
Range firstResult = null;
var currentResult = xlrange.Find(What: searchFor,
    LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole,
    SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows
);

while(currentResult != null)
{
    if (firstResult == null)
        firstResult = currentResult;

    else if (currentResult.get_Address(XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
             == firstResult.get_Address(XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
    {
        break;
    }

    currentResult.EntireRow.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGray;
    currentResult = xlrange.FindNext(currentResult);
}
```

Comment: This seems to only highlight the first row. It doesnt do it for each row?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This seems to have now highlighted everything in grey?

Comment: It highlights the entire rows, where a cell in column has "no" string. works perfectly on my excel.

Comment: Thats so weird - that column format is general (not text) that shouldnt cause issues should it? Also that column has a dropdown functionality which allows users to turn it to a Yes. Could this cause issues?

Comment: So i can see it looping into the while loop for each row so it looks like my currentResult is not working the way yours is working. Not sure why it seems to think each row has a "No" in it - because there are definately some 'Yes" in there

Comment: Is this the same code ? Are you sure you are calling FindNext ?

Comment: Ok ive investigated more - it looks like it works on a standard cell. The column V i have is a drop down list of either Yes or No. Not sure if excel interprets this differently but it cant seem to find the ones set to Yes or No? I tried with a different column and the above code works. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer. I change the LookAt flag to XlLookAt.xlWhole. In the previous implementation, it was searching for all cells that begin with 'no'.